# What is the complete list of file functions equivalent to the "strace -e file" options?

Tags: files, monitoring, debugging, system-calls, strace

According to `man strace` the `-e file` option traces all syscalls which take a file name as an argument. What is the whole set?

```
          %file
          file   Trace all system calls which take a file name as an
                 argument.  You can think of this as an abbreviation
                 for -e trace=open,stat,chmod,unlink,...  which is
                 useful to seeing what files the process is
                 referencing.  Furthermore, using the abbreviation
                 will ensure that you don't accidentally forget to
                 include a call like lstat(2) in the list.  Betchya
                 woulda forgot that one.  The syntax without a
                 preceding percent sign ("-e trace=file") is
                 deprecated.
```

There are some web pages with tables which list the syscalls, eg [ChromiumOS Docs - Linux System Call Table](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/constants/syscalls.md), [System calls table for several architectures](https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/download/tables/syscalls.html), as well as source code files of `strace syscallsent.h` eg [strace syscallsent.h](https://gitlab.com/strace/strace/-/blob/master/src/linux/x86_64/syscallent.h).

There are some obvious functions at the top of the `syscallent.h` such as  such as `read,write, open, close, stat, fstat` etc, which all seem to have `TD` and `TF` in the parameter names. Do they encompass all the functions which take filenames as arguments or are there others which don't have those parameters?

Comment: They are the ones marked with `TF` in the `linux/<arch>/syscallent.h` files. `TD` is for `-t desc`.

Comment: `read()`, `write()`, `fstat()` and `close()` don't take file path arguments, they take file `desc`riptors though.

Comment: source code is available - have you tried to check it?

Comment: My knowledge of C isn't that great